# CSS Accordion/Tree Menu with 100% width dividers

Tags: css, tree, accordion

I want to create a CSS/JS accordion menu, with HTML like so:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

The nav structure can get N levels deep, and each child menu will be indented from its parent. I want there to be a border that spans 100% of the width **between all nav elements including the n-th level child elements**. Like this:

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/64548/nested-nav.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/64548/nested-nav.png)

I cannot for the life of me figure out an easy way to do this without using JavaScript, but it feels like something that should be possible. (I will be using JS to expand/collapse the nav tree).

Comment: I had considered using a tiling bg image for the divider rows, but then the text couldn't be resize (as far as I know...)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the border and padding on the `<a>` which also must be set to `display:block`. This gives an added bonus as it makes the whole `<li>` region clickable.

There is no extra markup needed in the ul. Just define the max number of sublists in your css.

[Example here](http://ejgejg.com/test/menu.html)

```
a {text-decoration:none;}
ul {width:240px;padding:0;list-style:none;border-top:1px solid #000;}
ul ul, ul ul ul {border-top:0;}
li a {border-bottom:1px solid #000;display:block;padding-left:0px;}
li li a {padding-left:40px;}
li li li a {padding-left:80px;}


<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First Link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Child One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Child Two</a>
                <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Child Two One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Child Two Two</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Second Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The tiling background image for the divider rows does not contradict resizing (at least should not, with sane CSS renderers).

Comment: I think he's saying on a text-only zoom, the effect will break because the image will not scale. Page zoom will show no issues though, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty sloppy for my tastes, but basically it <strike>requires `text-indent` instead of `padding` or `margin` to achieve the nesting. But then to use a sprite image as the bullet for the `<a>`, you have to end up taking the current `text-indent` for the level and bump the sprite image over that many `px`, minus the sprite image width.</strike>

I've changed it to use `padding-left` on the `anchor` instead, but then this requires `overflow: hidden` on the parent `div` to hide the extra border that gets pushed to the right with each nesting.

And of course, visualize any of the stuff like `.two_deep`, `.expanded`, etc. as being done with jQuery, and NOT hardcoded into the CSS. It should be fairly simple to get a `ul`'s depth in the menu.

```
<html>
<head>    
    <style>
        body {font: normal 11px Arial;}

        a:link, a:visited {color: #888; text-decoration: none;}
        a:hover, a:active {color: #000; text-decoration: none;}

        div {width: 250px; border-top: 1px solid #888; overflow: hidden;}

        ul {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0; padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        li {
            padding: 5px 0;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
        }

        .two_deep li a {
            padding-left: 25px;
        }

        .three_deep li a {
            padding-left: 50px;
        }

        .four_deep li a {
            padding-left: 75px;
        }

        .expanded {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
            margin: -5px 0 5px;
            padding: 5px 0;
        }

        li > ul {margin: -5px 0 -6px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="expanded" href="#">First Link</a>
            <ul class="two_deep">
                <li><a href="#">Child One</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a class="expanded" href="#">Child Two</a>
                    <ul class="three_deep">
                        <li>
                            <a class="expanded" href="#">Child One of Child Two</a>
                            <ul class="four_deep">
                                <li><a href="#">Child One of . . .</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Child Two of . . .</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Child Two of Child Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Second Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Third Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But honestly, maybe you would rather just use a background image, and have it look ugly/broken when text is resized. The css is a bit 'hack-y' for my tastes, especially all the padding compensation needed due to the `anchor` and `li` having to be siblings.

I've tested this in Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, and Opera 9.6. I don't have access to anything else at the moment, so it's probably not even very pretty.

Needless to say it's **probably a complete wreck in all IE versions**. Sorry… It was just my own little test to see if I was up to the task!

Edit: It DOES work with page zoom and text resize, but again, IE support (?)…